# Adding more already installed OS's to BURG

Tags: burg, fedora

Can I add more already installed operating systems [such as BLAG linux or Fedora] to BURG [after BURG is installed] so they will appear on boot menu?

Answer (score 2):

`BURG` is based on `grub2` and doesn't use menu.lst.

The configuration file is in `/boot/burg/burg.cfg` and is generated automatically using scripts in `/etc/burg.d/` directory.

To add new boot items, modify `/etc/burg.d/40_custom`.

It is based on `GRUB2` so you can use method to add entries as of `grub2`.

```
menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 2.6.38-8-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    recordfail
    set gfxpayload=$linux_gfx_mode
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='(/dev/sda,msdos3)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root b61fcae3-7744-45b4-95b9-7528d50a3652
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.38-8-generic root=UUID=b61fcae3-7744-45b4-95b9-7528d50a3652 ro   quiet splash vt.handoff=7
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-2.6.38-8-generic
}
```

- How can I remove GRUB2 entries in Fedora 16? [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31406/how-can-i-remove-grub2-entries-in-fedora-16)
- Fedora's [guide to grub2 here](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/GRUB_2)
- Learn [more here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Burg)

### If you want to do it using GUI tool

> Grub Customizer is a graphical interface to configure the grub2/burg
>   settings with focus on the individual list order - without losing the
>   dynamical behavior of grub.
>
> To get more information about how it works, look here:
>   https://answers.launchpad.net/grub-customizer/+faq/1355. Version 2.0
>   introduces the ability to change the grub2/burg setting like the
>   default entry, timeouts, menu visibility, screen resolution,
>   background image and colors (grub2 only) and much more.
>
> You can use it to repair and configure grub2/burg using a live cd
>   (and Grub Customizer, which has to be installed as usual at the live
>   system before using it). All the required partitions will be
>   automatically mounted when choosing the root partition and some sub
>   partitions on the "partition chooser" (a dialog which pops up, when
>   you start Grub Customizer inside a live system).

You can also check out other details about Grub Customizer 2.5.6 and 2.5.5 on their [Official Website.](https://launchpad.net/grub-customizer)

**Download Tarballs of Grub Customizer 2.5.6 and 2.5.5 for Ubuntu, Linux Mint and Other Linux Distros**

[grub-customizer_2.5.6.tar.gz](https://launchpad.net/grub-customizer/2.5/2.5.6/+download/grub-customizer_2.5.6.tar.gz)

[grub-customizer_2.5.5.tar.gz](https://launchpad.net/grub-customizer/2.5/2.5.5/+download/grub-customizer_2.5.5.tar.gz)

### To install in UBUNTU

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

#### These links may help you

https://launchpad.net/~danielrichter2007/+archive/grub-customizer

https://answers.launchpad.net/grub-customizer/+faq/1397

https://answers.launchpad.net/grub-customizer/+faq/1355%20

### There is another tool

[Another tool and tutorial here](http://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/manage-plymouth-burg-grub-with-super-boot-manager/)